# Is there a way to to open a google doc in a new tab in button's serverClickHandler?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to to open a google doc in a new tab in button's serverClickHandler?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Anchor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_anchor) instead of a button

Answer (score 0):

If you need a button. You can put a link over a button and make things transparent etc. But it is messy. I suspect HTMLService is a much cleaner way, but have not tried to do it with HTMLService.

How to hover stuff, use 
 widget.setStyleAttribute("position", "absolute");

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a button to call a function?
it is better to create an anchor (link)

BEST ANSWER FOR SRIK!!